# What's the default fromdate for the /users/{id}/reputation route?

Tags: support, reputation, users

I'm getting different amounts of `positive-rep` when I use the `fromdate` and `todate` parameters with the /users/{id}/reputation route than when I don't use those parameters and accept the defaults.  I assume the `todate` parameter defaults to right now, but how far back should I set the `fromdate` to get the same behavior as the default?

Examples:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1288/reputation?pagesize=1
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1288/reputation?pagesize=1&fromdate=0